# Minibatch Weighted Sampling for estimating log(q_z) for disentangled representation based on ELBO loss in VAE

Tags: probability, estimation, autoencoders

I'm reading the paper "Isolating Sources of Disentanglement in VAEs" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04942.pdf. Assuming $p(n)$ is a uniform distribution and that we have a model to get $q(z|n)$ for any input n. Also, $q(z|n)$ represents a normal distribution, so the model predicts the mean and covariance matrix for $q(z|n)$. Please consider the following minibatch-based estimation provided by the author.

[image: Snippet from the paper]

Doubt 1. I'm not able to understand how to come from the second line to the third line, where $E_{p(B_M)}$ is introduced along with averaging over the values of $q(z|n_m)$. It is somewhat intuitive, but I'd like to know concretely. 
Doubt 2. What happened to the $E_r(B_M|n)$ coming to S4.

I'm sorry, if these are too trivial. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking at this formula recently. Based on my understanding,
$$E_{p(B_M)}[\frac{1}{M}\Sigma_{m=1}^{M}q(z|n_m)]=E[\frac{1}{M}\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} 1(i\in B_M)q(z|n_i)]=E[1(i\in B_M)](\frac{1}{M}\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} q(z|n_i))=\frac{M}{N}(\frac{1}{M}\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} q(z|n_i))=E_{p(n)}[q(z|n)]$$

Assuming the sampling is uniformly at random.

Comment: Hi, thnx for answering. But, wouldn't $E[1(i \in B_M)] = \sum_{i \in B_M}P(B_M) = (N^M - (N-1)^M) / N^M$

Comment: Hi! Assuming sampling with replacement:
Denote M as batch size and B as the number of batches. It is trivial to know that $$B=\frac{N!}{M!(N-M)!}$$. Then:
$$E_{P(B_M)}[1(i\in B_M)]=\Sigma_{b=1}^{B} P_{B_{Mb}}i(i\in B_{Mb})(1)$$
We also know that $$P_{B_{Mb}}=\frac{1}{B}$$ regardless of b. Then the RHS of eq.1 is $$\Sigma_{b=1}^{B}\frac{1}{B}1(i\in B_{Mb})(2)$$
Given a specific i, the number of items  in which $$1(i\in B_{Mb})=1$$ is $$\frac{(N-1)!}{(N-M)!(M-1)!}$$. Thus the final result of LHS in eq.1 should be:
$$\frac{(N-M)!M!}{N!} \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-M)!(M-1)!}=\frac{M}{N}$$

Comment: Your Doubt2 also confused me and Let me try to think about it.

Comment: I am sorry I think there are some problems for mine which is "sampling without replacement" while this paper is talking about "sampling with replacement" and to some extent I think your answer is correct.

Comment: Well I have to say that the minibatch weighted sampling is not "directly" correct for a couple of reasons. First, it can not go from first line to second line. Second, in the second line it should be q(z) rather than q(z,n). Third, it does not make any sense that you need the inequality term. More, the real machine learning is "sampling with replacement" and the i.i.d (aka sampling without replacement) is correct. My thought.

Comment: Wait guy! Got it! It does matter "sampling with replacement or sampling without replacement." For you answer:
$$\frac{N^M-(N-1)^M}{N^M}=1-(1-\frac{1}{N})^M \approx 1-(1-\frac{M}{N})=\frac{M}{N}$$(By Taylor approximation)

Comment: "Typo, ''It does not matter"

Comment: Wow! Taylor expansion was great. However, there is still a difference, one is biased, other is not. In section C.2 in the paper they calculate a unbiased Estimation of q(z) , using the same. So, I believe we are looking for unbiased one.

Comment: Also, since we are allowing replacement, we should instead be looking at
\begin{equation}
E(\text{#} i \in B_M) \\
= \frac{1}{N^M}\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}(M-i)(N-1)^i \\
\text{let }r = N-1,\text{ then}  \\
= \frac{1}{N^M}\frac{M(1-r) + r(r^M - 1)}{(1-r)^2}  \\
= \frac{(N-1)^{M+1} - N(M+1) + 1}{N^{M+2}} \\
\end{equation}